# How can I add text in text area after I push value using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I check box I get value and How can I add default text value

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#email_getdata').click(function() {
      var favorite = [];
      $.each($("input[name='find_product']:checked"), function() {
        favorite.push($(this).val());
      });
        $("#getdata_checked").html("ITEM : " + favorite.join(",  "));
        // I want to add text after I get value here
        $( "$getdata_checked" ).after(function() {
          $("#getdata_checked").html("rrr: ");
        });

    });
  });
```

I want to add default text in text area after I get item value

I want to display something like `item1,item2` <- which I already get by input check

Comment: If you click the `<>` button in the editor, you can provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch content using `$("#getdata_checked").html()` and then append it..

```
$( "$getdata_checked" ).after(function() {
  var content = $(this).html();
  $("#getdata_checked").html("rrr: " + content);
});
```